# Firebase Signup - Storing additional data in DB blocks the listener

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swiftui

On Firebase signup, I store additional data in a Realtime database. The problem is that somehow the AuthListener stops working then. Which means users have to restart the app.

This is my code

```
session.signUp(email: email, password: password) { (authData, error) in
    session.createUser()
}
```

.createUser adds an object to my realtime database. That part works well.

This part below create the problems

```
func listen() {
        _ = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { (auth, user) in
            if let user = user {
                self.ref = Database.database().reference(withPath: "\(String(describing: Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid ?? "Error"))")

                self.ref.child("user").observe(DataEventType.value) { (snapshot) in
                    self.user = MyModel(snapshot: snapshot)
                }
```

It looks like *self.user* doesn't get refreshed and my UI is dependent on this variable.

Thanks so much!

Comment: So for more clarity, when the user finishes the sign-up process, you will then call upon Firebase Authentication (not Realtime DB) to create the new user, as well as also storing the user within the Realtime Database, and then when trying to update the app state's user immediately after sign-up, the self.user isn't set from the listener?

Comment: @KyleBeard Correct, besides that I don't set self.user manually. It's also in the listener (as per the second code snippet).

Comment: Firebase Authentication only stores user emails and encrypted passwords, so besides their email, I would recommend just creating a 'users' portion of your Realtime Database which would allow you store their email, username, name, and any other relevant information your app requires that matches the Auth(). Since only one user would be using your app per their device, listening for the user to change doesn't seem very effective since you can already infer who your user is for that instance since they just signed up. So creating a RTDB write then also storing that object local would work right?

Comment: You do realize the path you're observing is */firebase_root/uid/user/* where normally it would be */firebase_root/users/uid*? You could replace this `self.ref = Database.database().reference(withPath: "\(String(describing: Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid ?? "Error"))")` with this `let userRef = self.ref.child("users").child(user.uid)`

Comment: @Jay I didn't structure the data in this way. Yes, beginners mistake. But that's why your suggestion won't fix it. It also works after restarting the app once. So the problem lies in the fact that I create the user object and somehow the listener doesn't pick it up

Comment: @KyleBeard I already store it in a RTDB as you describe. So you are suggesting to just assign self.user with the content as opposed to listen to it?

Comment: You may want to check the documentation for [addStateDidChangeListener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebaseauth/api/reference/Classes/Auth#addstatedidchangelistener_:) as it doesn't seem like it's the right function for this use. It will be called initially, when a *different* user signs in or when the user signs out. Quitting the app and going back in doesn't sign out or change users. Can you clarify the question so we understand what your trying to do?

Comment: @Jay the problem basically is that users need to restart the app to get the /user/uid data (the UI relies on that). In that case the listener works just fine. But in the case of the registration it just won't load this information. But maybe it's also just too specific to my case

Comment: I don't understand. When you're talking about registration, that would happen before the user exists and before their data is in Firebase. After they register the uid is populated and firebase keeps them authenticated (for a time), even when quitting the app so they don't have to re-authenticate each time the app opens. Perhaps clarifying the question as to what you're attempting to do will help? What exactly are you wanting to observe - what changes? What do you expect will fire that event (and why) and what action will be taken once whatever happens... happens?

Comment: @Jay The flow: a user registers via email/password. On success, I create the user in the realtime database (uid/user). The view is reliant on this just created object. That's why on signup the user doesn't get redirected to the signed in view. Closing the app and re-opening solves that. To me it looks like there is some race condition.

Comment: I get that the user signs up (which authenticates them) and some information is stored in the database. You state the view is reliant on this just created object - which object? the Auth Object or something else? Close and opening the app solves what exactly? The issue you're encountering is still unclear and what you're trying to do is also unclear. Can you clarify what you're asking and what the issue is? Update the *question* with that info so future readers will see it there instead of having to search through the comments for clarity.

Comment: @Jay I really don't know how to describe this any better. 
Which object => the one I create on successful signup aka the user in the realtime database
What does re-opening the app solve? The missing user object (not Auth). Then the app also shows the right state. 

What am I trying to achieve? Show the right state inside the app after successful signup.

Comment: Here's the issue: *Which object => the one I create on successful signup aka the user in the realtime database*. When a user signs up, a Firebase [AuthDataResult](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebaseauth/api/reference/Classes/AuthDataResult) object is created that contains the user information and will have an associated uid. That does **not** create a user in the realtime database. It only creates Firebase Authentication user object. YOU have to create a node in the Real Time Database that contains whatever other user information you want to store.

Comment: Again, per above, the code in the question will not work. You user is not changing states so `.addStateDidChangeListener` will never be called. Also, you're not showing how your user data is being written to Firebase in the first place. Also *Then the app also shows the right state* is vague - what is the 'right state' and where is it being shown? How are you getting the 'state'?

Comment: @Jay if you see my question (first code block), you see that saving the user is not the problem. It is successfully saved in the RTDB, that's why I can re-starting the app also works. 
I understand that `.addStateDidChangeListener` might not be the right method. But if e.g. a todo is added in `uid/todo` than it does get reflected in the UI, because I observe the todo. Equally am I observing the `uid/user` object. And this is the part that I don't understand. Why would the listener not get that change and assign the user object.

Comment: Whats read from the Database is not a 'user object'. It's JSON that could be anything. Restarting the app works because the currently auth'd user is persisted locally so they don't have to log in every time. That eventually expires. It appears the problem is the auth listener is not executing because the state isn't changing. Add a breakpoint here `self.user = MyModel(snapshot: snapshot)` and see if it fires. If it does, please include more code in the question so we can duplicate the issue. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)